# Modal Interchange chord progression (bVIIM7 moving to IM7)

Tags: chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions

[image]

I was reading a theory book and it's talking about "Modal Interchange."
The key is in C Major and I can't understand how BbM7 went to CM7. Isn't BbM7 a secondary triad Sub Dominant? And as I know, a secondary triad Sub Dominant can't just skip to the Primary triad Tonic..
So what is happening here?

Comment: Can you please edit your title to ask the question. It is not helpful to just have "modal interchange chord." Thanks.

Comment: @DrMayhem Sorry about that ! I fixed it !

Comment: What theory book is this?

Comment: Thanks Hyun - much easier to find in a search now!

Answer (score 4):

What's this idea that one chord CAN'T skip to another?   Bbmaj7 demonstrably CAN go straight to Cmaj7.   Do you like the sound?  Good.  Add it to your bag of musical resources.   If you subscribe to some system of 'theory' that says it can't be done, find a better sysyem of theory!

Theory describes.  It does not give permission.

I'm going to keep saying this until it sinks in!   Seems to be taking a long time :-)

Comment: I read that "Secondary Triad" chords ( iim7 ,iiim7 ,Vim7 , ) can't skip to the next function (ex. In C Maj key , Dm7 (Secondary Triad Sub Dominant) can't go to C Maj (Primary Triad Tonic) without going to its next function "Dominant" But the Primary Triads ( I , IV , V ) could skip to the next function ( ex. In C Maj key F - C or C - G ) so I was wondering if the Modal Interchange chord bVIIM7 ( Sub Dominant ) was a Primary Triad since the Sub Dominant was skipping to C ( Tonic ) or there might be other reasons that makes it possible

Comment: You're approaching this from the wrong direction.  Theory isn't a set of rules telling what you MAY do, it's a set of descriptions of what sounds good, or of what fits a certain style.

Comment: Yes I believe theory could be bended. But even those cases it has some reasons why that works and sounds fine.

Comment: There may be deep conceptual reasons why one musical event sounds better than another.  But the 'reasons' we are usually given more often justify something merely on the grounds that it's been noticed and categorised.  There are systems of categorisation based on functional harmony.  But they are not exclusive.  'It's next door' is also a perfectly good excuse for moving to a chord!

Comment: @HyunYooPark - who states that Dm7 can't go straight to C maj? Lots of music does exactly that, so this guy must have lived under a stone for a while. As Laurence says about 'theory'. That's just what it is. If everyone stuck to 'the rules', we'd all still be singing some pretty boring stuff!

Comment: Laurence, I know sometimes I give you a bit of a hard time for being brutally direct, but you are absolutely on the money with that middle paragraph.

Comment: @DrMayhem - too true! It seems that there are more and more questions such as these. No-one's listening to Laurence!

Answer (score 0):

i 'm studing a theory book that talk about the bVIIM7 function.These chords are non diatonic chords inherited from the Myxolidian mode.Their function us a SUB-DOMINANT function.
For instance in G Major you can find an FM7 because in G mixolydian the F is not #, as in a G7 chord. The bVIIM7 chords tend to resolve on I. But as a sub-dominant chord, you can find it in a IV-V-I cadence where the bVIIM7 take place of the IV. This the case in the pop song i'm studying where FM7 (bVIIM7) is preceded by a C (IV) and followed  a D7 (V7) and a G (I). This emphasizes its a SUB-DOMINANT function ( I Need you by America  - 1971)
Cheers !